# Implement status 200 when DELETE is send

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I want to implement DELETE request with Spring Boot. I tried this:

```
@DeleteMapping("remove/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> remove(@PathVariable String id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(transactionNotesService.delete(Long.valueOf(id)))
                .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
    }
```

But I get `The method ok(T) in the type ResponseEntity is not applicable for the arguments (void)`.

How I can modify the code to return code 200 when DELETE is performed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [HTTP Spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) you should always have a body with status 200.

> **10.2.1 200 OK**
>
> The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response is dependent on the method used in the request, for example:
>
> GET an entity corresponding to the requested resource is sent in the response;
>
> HEAD the entity-header fields corresponding to the requested resource are sent in the response without any message-body;
>
> POST an entity describing or containing the result of the action;
>
> TRACE an entity containing the request message as received by the end server.

You should use status 204 (No Content) instead, which doesn't take a body argument.

> **10.2.5 204 No Content**
>
> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

```
transactionNotesService.delete(Long.valueOf(id));
return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
```

Comment: This is one way of doing this. Another would be to return the deleted entity.

Comment: I get `The method orElseGet(() -> {}) is undefined for the type ResponseEntity.HeadersBuilder<capture#21-of ?>`

Comment: Yeah, I removed that. You'll have to rewrite your logic to return not found. The question doesn't contain enough information for me to know what `transactionNotesService.delete` returns.

Comment: Plus one for returning 204 no content on a delete

Comment: I'm forced to change the return type to HeadersBuilder<?> Is this correct?

Comment: No, there should be a `.build()` after `noContent()`. It seems I haven't used `ResponseEntity` for a while :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid unnecessarily `Long.valueOf(id)`

Spring can parse it automatically:

`public ResponseEntity<?> remove(@PathVariable Long id)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are confusing ResponseEntity.ok() and ResponseEntity.ok(T t) where t is something you wish to be returned.

If transactionNotesService.delete or notFound().build are have void as the return type then you can't use them as the return value because they have no value. I'm guessing you meant something like this:

```
@DeleteMapping("remove/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> remove(@PathVariable String id) {
    transactionNotesService.delete(Long.valueOf(id));
    return ResponseEntity.noContent();
}
```

Comment: One question: When I add `return ResponseEntity.noContent();` I'm forced to change the return type to `HeadersBuilder<?>` Is this correct?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ResponseEntity.noContent().build()`?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you could probably return 200 or 204 (202 being for asynchronous/in progress deleting) as stated by [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE) :

> If a DELETE method is successfully applied, there are several response
>   status codes possible:
>
> A 202 (Accepted) status code if the action will likely succeed but has
>   not yet been enacted.
>
> A 204 (No Content) status code if the action has been enacted and no
>   further information is to be supplied.
>
> A 200 (OK) status code if the action has been enacted and the response
>   message includes a representation describing the status.

For a `204` what you want is :

```
return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
```

For a `200` what you want is for example :

```
return ResponseEntity.ok("Entity deleted");
```

**Code change to return `204`**

In your actual code the `orElseGet()` part should not compile since `ok()` doesn't return an `Optional`.
To handle the case of the id passed by the client doesn't have any matching with any existing entity, you could catch `EmptyResultDataAccessException` (a RuntimeException subclass) that is thrown by `JpaRepository.deleteById()`.
For example :

```
@DeleteMapping("remove/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> remove(@PathVariable String id) {
  try{
    transactionNotesService.delete(Long.valueOf(id)); 
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();        
   }
   catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
      return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
  }                                
 }
```